# Deleting sequential duplicates from a concatenated string

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am running a query thats concatenating the actions taken in an entire session into one string, reducing each hit down to (Pageview or Event) / (the page or the type of event)

It then puts them into a big long string that goes

```
Pageview / a >>> Pageview / b
```

Issue is that currently I am getting a lot of strings that go

```
Pageview /a >>> Pageview /a >>> Pageview /a >>> Event / b >>> Pageview /a >>> Pageview /a
```

Which is an expected behaviour on the site, just not the output I'm looking for.

What I'm looking to do is to delete sequential duplicates but not delete if the same pageview happens at two seperate points in the session. So in the case of the example above it would become:

```
Pageview /a >>> Event / b >>> Pageview /a
```

For some additional context, I am unable to control the shape of the original input, but I can tweak how the data is concatenated. So I can do this deletion before the concatenation occurs if that is more straightforward

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  I wouldn't recommend trying to fix the string *after* it is produced.  Show a simplified version of your query so it can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

After the fact, you can remove adjacent duplicates from the string by doing the following:

- Split the string to an array
- Expand the array to a table
- Look for adjacent values that are different
- Reaggregate as a string

In BigQuery this is:

```
select (select string_agg(s.s, ' >>> ')
        from (select s, lag(s) over (order by n) as prev_s
              from unnest(split(str, ' >>> ')) s with offset n
             ) s
        where s.prev_s is null or s.prev_s <> s.s
       ) 
from (select 'Pageview /a >>> Pageview /a >>> Pageview /a >>> Event / b >>> Pageview /a >>> Pageview /a' as str
     ) x
```

As I mention in a comment, you should probably do this in the original query.  If you want help with that, ask a *new* question (this one has been answered).

Also, you should probably get used to working with arrays.  They are generally more powerful than strings.

Answer (score 0):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL and not just collapses duplicate items but also counts and presents respective counts in output

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'Pageview /a >>> Pageview /a >>> Pageview /a >>> Event / b >>> Pageview /a >>> Pageview /a' AS actions UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, 'Pageview /1 >>> Pageview /1 >>> Pageview /2 >>> Event / 3 >>> Pageview /1 >>> Pageview /1' 
)
SELECT id, 
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(line, ' >>> ' ORDER BY grp) FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT(action, ' (', CAST(COUNT(1) AS STRING), ')') line, grp FROM (
      SELECT action, COUNTIF(flag) OVER(ORDER BY OFFSET) grp
      FROM (
        SELECT  action, OFFSET, action != LAG(action) OVER(ORDER BY OFFSET) flag
        FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(actions, ' >>> ')) action WITH OFFSET
    ))
    GROUP BY action, grp
  )) compressed_actions
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

```
Row id  compressed_actions   
1   1   Pageview /a (3) >>> Event / b (1) >>> Pageview /a (2)    
2   2   Pageview /1 (2) >>> Pageview /2 (1) >>> Event / 3 (1) >>> Pageview /1 (2)
```